# Returning round value but still printing the whole decimal points

Tags: python, printing, rounding

So I want to get the output value of my function below having maximum 4 decimal points. So I wrote return `round(val,4)`. But when I'm printing the function with arguments, the output is not rounded and shows all the decimal points.

```
def longhike(capacity, *val_weights):
vals=[]
weights=[]
unitval=[]
for i in range (0,len(val_weights),2):
    vals.append(val_weights[i])
    weights.append(val_weights[i+1])
    unitval.append(val_weights[i]/val_weights[i+1])
#print(unitval, vals, weights)
val=0

maxval= max(unitval)
maxidx= unitval.index(maxval)

while capacity>0:
    if weights[maxidx]>=capacity:
        val+= unitval[maxidx]*capacity
        return val
    
    else:
        capacity= capacity-weights[maxidx]
        #print(f'capacity={capacity}')
        val+=vals[maxidx]
        #print(val)
        del vals[maxidx]
        del weights[maxidx]
        del unitval[maxidx]
        #print(vals, weights, unitval, maxidx, maxval)
        maxval= max(unitval)
        maxidx= unitval.index(maxval)
        #print(maxval, maxidx)
        
return round(val,4)
    
print(longhike(50, 60,20,100,50,120,30))
print(longhike(10, 500,30))
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation.

Comment: You aren't rounding `val` in the `if` block `return` statement

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's happening, but above the last `return`, you also `return val`. Hav eyou checked your code step by step to see which `return` you're triggering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not rounding the 'val' in your return function, at the end of the first if statement, following should work:

```
def longhike(capacity, *val_weights):

vals=[]
weights=[]
unitval=[]
for i in range (0,len(val_weights),2):
    vals.append(val_weights[i])
    weights.append(val_weights[i+1])
    unitval.append(val_weights[i]/val_weights[i+1])
#print(unitval, vals, weights)
val=0

maxval= max(unitval)
maxidx= unitval.index(maxval)

while capacity>0:
    if weights[maxidx]>=capacity:
        val+= unitval[maxidx]*capacity
        return round(val,4)
    
    else:
        capacity= capacity-weights[maxidx]
        #print(f'capacity={capacity}')
        val+=vals[maxidx]
        #print(val)
        del vals[maxidx]
        del weights[maxidx]
        del unitval[maxidx]
        #print(vals, weights, unitval, maxidx, maxval)
        maxval= max(unitval)
        maxidx= unitval.index(maxval)
        #print(maxval, maxidx)
        
return round(val,4)

print(longhike(50, 60,20,100,50,120,30))
print(longhike(10, 500,30))
```